# change ip to dns in /etc/hosts on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ip, hosts-file

in ubuntu 11.04, i'm trying to change dns to force it to point to another server
let's assume the domain name is www.mysite.com
and the ip 96.32.66.xx

i changed /etc/hosts but when i open the browser it dosen't work.

if i ping 96.32.66.xxx it works
on windows i applied the same change in system32/drivers/etc/hosts and it works

this is my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   trustweb-Linux   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1   trustweb-Linux   localhost6.localdomain6   localhost6
127.0.1.1   trustweb-Linux

96.32.66.xxx www.miosito.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I execute this code to refresh the net cache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

what's wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart networking.  Did you restart your browser?

Comment: That's obviously **not** your `/etc/hosts`.  That's a file with a syntax error that will cause the very behaviour that you describe.  Show people your _actual_ data, not something that you made up in the question.

Comment: yes it was not the complete file, i changed only the last two numbers of ip address and the domain name. surely i had checked that string well before to post here...anyway, thank you to try to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `/etc/host.conf`.  It should say `order hosts,bind`, which tells it to believe `/etc/hosts` before it believes dns.

Comment: /etc/host.conf seems to be correct:  hosts,bins. The same for /etc/nsswitch.conf: hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proxy, name resolution will be completed on the proxy. I also had some problems with browsers needing to be completely closed and re-opened for the hosts changes to be recognized (like closing all instances/tabs/etc).

Comment: i think if it works on windows it should work on ubuntu...i also tryied delete chrome cache, and unflagging some option for dns i tryed also ff and opera....same story.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely name caching. On the Linux machine, restart nscd (the name service caching daemon). Plus, flush the cache in the browser.

Comment: i typed: sudo aptitude install nscd.....then....sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart....it dosen't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Strangely now it works...i didn't reboot the pc from yesterday, and i'm changing in the same way /etc/hosts file

how does it possible?